# What are some alternatives to least squares method?

Tags: approximation

I am now working on sir model for epidemic modeling and I am trying to estimate the parameters of the system using available data,but I have to approximate the points representing the variables with respect to time. So apart from the least squares method, what are some other methods that could solve this problem ?

Comment: Havent seen this for some time, but perhaps maximum likelihood estimation or parametric alternatives? I think you can try googling this.

Answer (score 0):

gradient descent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent
is an universal method to approximate any function or dataset

Comment: Thanks for your responses